# Bulk hide duplicated products with SQL woocommerce

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, duplicates

- I have 21k products from two suppliers. - wp_posts.post_author value '5' and '6'

  - Some products are sold by both of them (around 2k).
  - I want to hide catalog visibility for duplicates from post_author(vendor) '5'

I made this SQl query to find out duplicates

```
SELECT 
    pm.post_id, 
    pm.meta_value, 
    pm.meta_key, 
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_author, 
    p.id, p.post_type, COUNT(*)
FROM wp_postmeta pm
JOIN wp_posts p 
    ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND pm.meta_key = 'icecat_sku' 
AND pm.meta_value != '' 
GROUP BY meta_value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[Output of the first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj255.png)

- This works fine but its only showing duplicates from post_author(vendor) '6'.

So I tried to `SELECT` all products from post_author '5' to see if there is no issue with query

```
   SELECT 
    pm.post_id, 
    pm.meta_value, 
    pm.meta_key, 
    p.post_date,
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_author, 
    p.id, p.post_type
FROM wp_posts p 
JOIN wp_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND pm.meta_key = 'icecat_sku' 
AND pm.meta_value != ''
AND p.post_author = '5'
```

[Output of the second query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YJ5A.png)
- And it does just fine.

- So the main problem is when I'm adding:
  `GROUP BY meta_value
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

-This is problematic query to get duplicates from (vendor)post_author'5':

```
   SELECT 
    pm.post_id, 
    pm.meta_value, 
    pm.meta_key, 
    p.post_date,
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_author, 
    p.id, p.post_type, COUNT(*)
FROM wp_posts p 
JOIN wp_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
AND pm.meta_key = 'icecat_sku' 
AND pm.meta_value != ''
AND p.post_author = '5'
GROUP BY meta_value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[Output of third query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mta9Y.png)

- It returns only 16 products instead of 2k products...
- I believe that I'm wrong or missing something with `GROUP BY meta_value
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Can you please tell me if my queries have some issues which can cause the problems?
Already spend some days fixing this...
Thank you

Comment: Hi - Welcome to So. Some sample data would help to solve this. Please see this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @VarunT Thanks for the advice! I added pics of outcome from those queries home it will help